# Oracle In-line View Causing Update Expression Issues

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, case

I am receiving error "ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table" with this query:

```
UPDATE 
 (SELECT P.SERVICE_DATE_OUT AS P_DATEOUT, P.SERVICE_DATE_IN AS P_DATEIN
  FROM TRANSLOG TL JOIN PMEQMT P ON TL.ITEMNO = P.EQNO
  WHERE TL.LOC_DESC = 'E-IN SERVICE')
SET P_DATEOUT = NULL, P_DATEIN = NULL
```

After researching, I believe this error is due to creating an in-line view and the update trying to update both tables rather than the one I want? Can anyone confirm this? Is there a work around?

To further explain my scenario I have built two other queries that will run daily, prior to the above one running (if I can get something functioning).

First:

```
  UPDATE PMEQMT P
   SET SERVICE_DATE_OUT = (SELECT MAX(TL.TRANS_DATE)
                        FROM TRANSLOG TL
                        WHERE P.EQNO = TL.ITEMNO AND 
                              TL.LOC_DESC = 'E-OUT OF SERVICE' AND
                              TL.TRANS_DATE >= SYSDATE - 1 AND
                              TL.TRANS_IN_OUT = 'IN'
                       )
WHERE P.CLASS = 'TL' AND
      P.SERVICE_DATE_OUT IS NULL
```

Second:

```
UPDATE PMEQMT P
   SET SERVICE_DATE_IN =
   CASE 
   WHEN SERVICE_DATE_IN IS NULL THEN (SELECT MAX(TL.TRANS_DATE)
                        FROM TRANSLOG TL
                        WHERE P.EQNO = TL.ITEMNO AND 
                              TL.LOC_DESC = 'E-IN SERVICE' AND
                              TL.TRANS_DATE >= SYSDATE - 1 AND
                              TL.TRANS_IN_OUT = 'IN'
                       )
   WHEN (TRUNC(SERVICE_DATE_IN)) <= (TRUNC(SYSDATE)) THEN (SELECT ((TRUNC(SYSDATE))+1)
                        FROM TRANSLOG TL
                        WHERE P.EQNO = TL.ITEMNO AND
                        TL.LOC_DESC = 'E-OUT OF SERVICE'
                       )
   WHEN (TRUNC(SERVICE_DATE_IN)) > (TRUNC(SYSDATE)) THEN (SELECT SERVICE_DATE_IN 
                        FROM TRANSLOG TL
                        WHERE P.EQNO = TL.ITEMNO AND
                        TL.LOC_DESC = 'E-OUT OF SERVICE'
                       )
   END
WHERE CLASS = 'TL'
```

Is there a way to combine these? All three if the very first query becomes functioning, if not, then the last two? Does it make sense to combine them or am I better off leaving them separate?

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This first one can't work because you are trying to update a query and not a table. That's like trying to update a view. I think, for the first one, you want something like: UPDATE  PMEQMT P 
SET P_DATEOUT = NULL, P_DATEIN = NULL WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM  TRANSLOG TL WHERE TL.ITEMNO = P.EQNO 
  AND TL.LOC_DESC = 'E-IN SERVICE')

Comment: Susan's update looks good. But FYI you can actually update a subquery or a view - there are just restrictions. Here, the optimizer is complaining that it can't guarantee (using primary/unique keys) that your subquery will return a unique set of rows. See this Ask Tom: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:273215737113

Comment: I learned something new. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to your first query. In order to update a join view (the nested select turns into a view internally) the following conditions must be met:

- Any `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` operation on a join view can modify only one underlying base table at a time. (That's ok with your query, you're updating only `PMEQMT` table.)
- All updatable columns of a join view must map to columns of a [key-preserved table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views001.htm#i1006318). (And this is where you get into trouble).

The second condition means that each row of a table must have only one corresponding row in a joined table (one-to-one relationship).

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views001.htm#i1006232).

To get round this error you can rewrite your update statement to a merge statement:

```
merge into PMEQMT t
using (SELECT P.EQNO
          FROM TRANSLOG TL JOIN PMEQMT P ON TL.ITEMNO = P.EQNO
       WHERE TL.LOC_DESC = 'E-IN SERVICE') u
on (u.EQNO = t.EQNO)
when matched then update set t.P_DATEOUT = NULL, t.P_DATEIN = NULL;
```

Regarding two last queries, you can combine them into one query:

```
UPDATE PMEQMT P
   SET SERVICE_DATE_OUT = case when P.SERVICE_DATE_OUT IS NULL then(SELECT MAX(TL.TRANS_DATE)
                                                                    FROM TRANSLOG TL
                                                                    WHERE P.EQNO = TL.ITEMNO AND 
                                                                          TL.LOC_DESC = 'E-OUT OF SERVICE' AND
                                                                          TL.TRANS_DATE >= SYSDATE - 1 AND
                                                                          TL.TRANS_IN_OUT = 'IN'
                                                                   ) 
                          else P.SERVICE_DATE_OUT end,
       SERVICE_DATE_IN =
               CASE 
               WHEN SERVICE_DATE_IN IS NULL THEN (SELECT MAX(TL.TRANS_DATE)
                                    FROM TRANSLOG TL
                                    WHERE P.EQNO = TL.ITEMNO AND 
                                          TL.LOC_DESC = 'E-IN SERVICE' AND
                                          TL.TRANS_DATE >= SYSDATE - 1 AND
                                          TL.TRANS_IN_OUT = 'IN'
                                   )
               WHEN (TRUNC(SERVICE_DATE_IN)) <= (TRUNC(SYSDATE)) THEN (SELECT ((TRUNC(SYSDATE))+1)
                                    FROM TRANSLOG TL
                                    WHERE P.EQNO = TL.ITEMNO AND
                                    TL.LOC_DESC = 'E-OUT OF SERVICE'
                                   )
               WHEN (TRUNC(SERVICE_DATE_IN)) > (TRUNC(SYSDATE)) THEN (SELECT SERVICE_DATE_IN 
                                    FROM TRANSLOG TL
                                    WHERE P.EQNO = TL.ITEMNO AND
                                    TL.LOC_DESC = 'E-OUT OF SERVICE'
                                   )
               END     
WHERE P.CLASS = 'TL';
```

One single request to the database is always better then few consecutive. You can also consider rewriting inner repetitive queries, so you can get the result in one shot without hitting `TRANSLOG` table again and again.